# Views module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

What are the uses of views module in Drupal?

Comment: The question is, at the same time, both answered on the Views page and open-ended since one could always come with a new usage for Views. So not a very good question for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At its most basic level, Views is a query builder. It does much more than this though as it allows you to manage the output of your query results and set them up as pages, blocks, feeds, or any other number of output options that can be extended with other modules.

Views is one of the most heavily used modules in the Drupal community. It is currently reported as installed on 270,290 active sites.

Some examples of uses of Views from its [project page](http://drupal.org/project/views):

> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for that month.

Answer (score 3):

I usually describe is as a "visual query builder", like user247245. On a simpler level, Views can be useful any time you need a list of data "objects" (or their sub-components) from your site (whether content, users, comments, etc.).

A view can be as simple as a single item; for instance, if you want to have a featured story randomly inserted into a block on the sidebar of every page. Views lets you add filters (by date created, by taxonomy term, etc.), designate displays (block, page, etc.), and theme the output (at the display level, at the row level, etc).

A lot of the power of Views stems from the fact that it integrates with lots of other modules. It compliments [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) especially well, by allowing you to flexibly output CCK fields, as needed. And there are lots of other modules that add additional display types, such as [lightbox slideshows](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox), "[accordions](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion)", [CSV exports](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus), [JSON output](http://drupal.org/project/views_json), [carousels](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel), [calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar), etc.

In short, if you plan to use Drupal, time spent learning to use Views will be time well spent.

Answer (score 1):

It's a visual "query building tool", giving you the ability to fetch data (nodes).

Think of it as SQL "reinvented".

Answer (score 1):

On an even more basic level, you use Views to creates pages or blocks of lists. Like, lists of thumbnails with headlines and teasers, lists of users, lists of comments, and etc. Views extends making basic mysql querys and fetching rows, because you can format the display of the rows and fields to suit your needs.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

According to me there is no way to display one content type's contents on other content type page.. But by using views you can do it very easily.. You just have to add taxonomy terms and based on that you can display it very easily. You just have to create a proper relationship and have to apply the contexual filter for it..

e.g.

You have two content type :
1.Page,
2.Blog Entry

now if you want to display the page related blog on the page as a block then there is not other way than creating a view. and its a very simple way to do this.